# Как удалить дубликаты из ассоциативного массива, сравнив два поля

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется массив, каждый раз собирается динамически

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TO_USER_ID] => 5
            [TEXT] => Здравствуйте, Скворцов Лев Иванович!
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TO_USER_ID] => 4
            [TEXT] => Здравствуйте, Пупкин Никита Андреевич!
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [TO_USER_ID] => 1
            [TEXT] => Здравствуйте, Пушкин Иван Иванович!
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [TO_USER_ID] => 1
            [TEXT] => Здравствуйте, Пушкин Иван Иванович!
        )

)
```

Как можно проверить его на уникальность по ключам TO_USER_ID и TEXT. Текста, конечно, будет чуть больше, чем в примере, и он не всегда может совпадать, как с индексом 2 и 3.

Нужно как-то избавиться от подобных дублей, причем TO_USER_ID может быть в текстовом формате и числом (но обязательно это будет цифра).

Comment: `$a[2] == $a[3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
$uniq = array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: *Текста конечно будет чуть больше чем в примере, и не всегда может совпадать как с индексом 2 и 3* - в этом случае `array_unique` не поможет

Comment: Не вижу проблемы: `уникальность по ключам TO_USER_ID и TEXT`. Количество текста ни на что не влияет, несовпадающий(как в 2 и 3) текст является уникальным. Вопрос только в том, есть ли там ещё что-либо, кроме ключей, из текста вопроса можно заключить, что нет.